# How to ignore null values in mongodb insert query

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongodb-query

I am trying to insert some data into mongodb database from a simple registration form. It includes first name, middle name and last name in which middle name is optional. Now I want insert middle name into database only if user provides it in the form.

```
fname = request.values.get('fname')
mname = request.values.get('mname')
lname = request.values.get('lname')
db.users.insert({'fname':fname, 'mname':mname, 'lname':lname})
```

I am getting this output:

```
id:5d11c378f829d8938bf65e0b
fname:"test"
mname:""
lname:"user"
```

I want this( if mname is not provided in the form):

```
id:5d11c378f829d8938bf65e0b
fname:"test"
lname:"user"
```

```html
    <form action="/register" method="post">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="fname" required>
      <br>
       Middle name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="mname">  <!-- optional -->
        <br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lname" required>
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

```
return "Registered successfully!"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about check the empty value before insert?

```
var m = request.values.get(‘mname’);
mname = (m) ? m : null;
```

Or you can try insert object.

```
user.fname = request.values.get('fname')
var m = request.values.get(‘mname’)
user.lname = request.values.get('lname')
if (m){
  user.mname = m
}
db.users.insert(user)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But here I want write only one insert query like db.users.insert({'fname':fname, 'mname':mname, 'lname':lname}) and here if i check mname is null I have to change the whole query from db.users.insert({'fname':fname, 'mname':mname, 'lname':lname}) to db.users.insert({'fname':fname, 'lname':lname}) in case mname is null.

Comment: In my case, Instead of insert query, I did create object and insert it to db.